# Inductor choke value

Tags: inductor

Good day everyone, I extracted this inductor from old electronics, and from the code written on it I can not tell the value of the inductor. Please someone should help me out.
the picture of the inductor is attached below

[image: inductors part number]

[image: inductor picture]

[image: part number]

Comment: Most probably custom. Break out the LCR meter.

Comment: It does not even look like a simple inductor. It looks like it is a common mode choke, possibly from a mains input filter of the device.

Comment: Yes you're right it is a common mode choke